# An integral of $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}{x^2\ \mathrm{sech}(mx)\ \mathrm{sech}(nx)\ \mathrm{d}x}$, m,n $∈{\mathbb{R}_{+}}$

Tags: definite-integrals, mellin-transform

Following is the original integral:
$$F(m,n)=\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}{\dfrac{\arctan(x^{m})\arctan(x^{n})}{x}\ \mathrm{d}x}$$
Then, the bivariate function $F(m,n)$ is given the second partial derivative, first m and then n. Like:
$$\dfrac{\partial^2F(m,n)}{\partial m\partial n}=\dfrac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^2\ \mathrm{sech}(mx)\ \mathrm{sech}(nx)\ \mathrm{d}x}$$
I guess Merlin transformation or Ramanujan's master theorem is needed. However, I can't find the right way.

Comment: How did you get that for the second derivative?
$$\frac{d}{dm}\arctan(x^{-m})=\frac{-x^{-m}\ln{x}}{1+x^{-2m}}$$
Was there a substitution or something along the way?

Comment: Change of variable lnx -> t after two derivation

Comment: The original integral diverges unless $m < -1$, $n < -1$, or $m + n < -1$.